# Cycle as a product of disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles, algebraic-cycles

I have few permutation groups in product form and I want to express them as a product of disjoint cycles.
$$(4,5)(1,2,3)(3,2,1)(5,4)(2,6)(1,4)$$
I have two ways to solve the question and both seem correct to me, but they give different answers.

### Method 1:

Multiplication method
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
3 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 6
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1 & 6 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
4 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix} $$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
2 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
3 & 1 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
4 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
4 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 2
\end{pmatrix} $$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
4 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$(1,4)(2,6)$$

### Method 2:

Inverse multiplication, we observe that the $2\&3$ and $1\&4$ are inverse of each other, on simplification, this will give us $$(2,6)(1,4)$$
But, I know that permutations are not commutative. So where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: *Disjoint* cycles do commute.

Comment: Permutations in general may not always be commutative, but **disjoint** cycles do commute.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, observe that $(123)(321)=e$ and $(45)(54)=e$. Disjoint cycles commute. Your methods thus evaluate the permutation to equivalent forms.